# turn array into string and remove specific item

Tags: php, arrays

On my website I have a list of news available at `/news/`  which displays all news.  I allow news to be filtered based on subject by adding categories to the URL like: `/news/sports` or multiple categories `/news/sports+politics+crime`

Within my application I explode the URL on the `+` and build an array which I use to grab the correct news items.  In addition to grabbing the items, I also print "Tags" onto the page, with an "X" to remove the given category.  So if you went to `/news/sports+politics+crime` then above the list of News I have printed `Sports[X]  Politics[X] Crime[X]`

What I want to do, is like the `[X]` to the same URL MINUS the category that is being removed.  So the `href` tag of the crime `[X]` would be `/news/sports+politics` but the `href` tag of sports would be `/news/politics+crime`

What is the best way to do this?

While generating the page I am looping thru my array of categories like so:

```
foreach ($category as $cat) {
    echo $cat . '<a href="/news/">[X]</a>';
}
```

What is the best way to print the link without the category being removed?  I was thinking I could somehow flatten the array into a plain old string, and find/replace the given item ex `+crime` and then turn that back into a URL.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_diff()` to remove the current category from the `$category` array:

```
foreach ($category as $cat) {
  $other_categories = array_diff($category, array($cat));
  echo $cat . ' <a href="/news/' . implode('+', $other_categories) . '">[X]</a>';
}
```

Comment: Holy cow, that works perfectly.  That is much easier than I had expected.  Than you so much for the help